# how to enable/disable System fonts in Windows 10 using DWrite APIs

Tags: c++, directwrite

Hi I need to enable/disable system fonts in Windows 10 using DWrite APIs. Is there any flag by using that I can enable/disable fonts.

Answer (score 0):

By disable, do you mean uninstall? DWrite just reads whatever fonts are installed - it doesn't have permission to actually modify what is installed or not. To uninstall fonts, go to Windows settings \ Personalization \ Fonts \ click on the font \ click Uninstall button. Though, it's unwise to remove system fonts, because it will affect other programs which expect those fonts to exist.

Note you can see what font files are installed here:

Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts

(or if by "disable" you mean to just avoid using the system fonts in your specific application/IDWriteTextLayout, I can expand on the answer)